# Terminate Spring Batch if validation(violation count) exceed some predefined count in Item Processor

Tags: spring, validation, spring-batch

Is there any way in Spring Batch to stop the batch from proceeding further if validation count exceeds pre-defined count.

I am currently throwing the validation exception from item processor . But it just skips the item from sending to item writer not stopping the batch .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the fluent api (StepBuilder) you can set it as follows:

```
@Bean
public Step step(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<... , ...>chunk(1) 
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .faultTolerant()

            .skipLimit(10) 

            .build();
}
```

This will instantiate as LimitCheckingItemSkipPoliciy.

You can also instantiate or define your own SkipPolicy utilizing the skipPolicy method

```
        ...
        .faultTolerant()
        .skipPolicy(mySkipPolicy) 
        ...
```

If you want to set the skiplimit in an XML configuration:

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="flatFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter"
             commit-interval="10" 

             skip-limit="10">

         <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="..."/>
         </skippable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```